# In the readme for the Batch-Importer can someone clarify the constraints with examples

Tags: neo4j

**current limitations, constraints:**

have to know max # of rels per node, properties per node and relationship

relationships have to be pre-sorted by min(start,end)

What does Pre-Sorted mean and does it apply if I'm using automatic indexing.

Answer (score 1):

This is only relevant for the parallel batch-importer not for the normal one (which is usually fast enough).

What is your use-case? What does your data look like?

Soon there will be much better batch-import support in Neo4j itself.